# Subreport visibility

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a list of subreports in an SSRS report which all have a parameter of Client_No based from their original report. I then only want the subreport to show if the Client No in a dataset 'Summary' has that particular subreport set to 1. The fields of those subreports whether 1 or 0 is bit so I'm not sure if that's the problem but at the moment if I add the following code, it hides this particular subreport even if its set to 1 or 0 when it should only be visible if set to 1 for that particular client and subreport. Basically, different clients only want to see certain subreports.

```
=IIf(Parameters!Client_No.Value = Fields!Client.Value,"Summary" AND fields!Output.Value,"Summary" = "1!, False, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataset that return records filtered by Client_No = 1. then in subreport visibility set show condition on number of rows.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really understand what you mean? It will be the subreport names that are the fields = 1 I.e output

Comment: you must create a dataset in your subreport that filter data according to client_id. then in primary report you send proper client_id to subreport. now again in subreport set show condition for table on count of dataset records.

Comment: In my subreport dataset it already filters with the @Client_No parameter

Comment: so what's wrong?? set show condition on count of dataset records

Comment: sorry which dataset?